# unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in in YII PHP frameworke

Tags: php, yii

Application showing `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\wamp\www\basic\web\index.php on line 12`

and the 12 line is

```
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: That syntax (instantiating an object and immediately calling a method of that object, aka [Class member access on instantiation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)) requires PHP >= 5.4 - what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: i am using PHP 5.3.13

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP 5.3.13 (which is [no longer supported](http://php.net/eol.php) anyway) then you'll need to upgrade to PHP >= 5.4 (even 5.4 is only in [security support](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) until September this year)

or modify that line to something like:

```
$app = new yii\web\Application($config)
$app->run();
```